# To check whether my list fulfils the parameters set out in nested loop in scala function

Tags: scala, list, function, sorting, boolean

```
def sorted[A] (as: Array[A], p:(A,A,A)=Boolean): Boolean => {
def alpha(n: Array[String]): Boolean => {
    if (n()>=as()) true
    else if (!(p)as(n-1), as(n)) false
    else loop(n+1)

}
=alpha()
```

The question is to make a function checks if the input is sorted - and returns true if strings are sorted in ascending order i.e. (sorted A to Z) but false otherwise.

Comment: That is not valid Scala code

Comment: Are you saying, 3 elements of any type, any order OR any number of strings in ascending order OR ints from the Fibonacci sequence in ascending order?

Comment: I'm using a Scala interpreter in python! @jwvh Yep for any of those conditions it returns a True

Comment: @Lasf I am using a Scala interpreter in Python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to determine which type of `Array` you're dealing with.

```
def arrTest[A](a :Array[A]) :Boolean = a match {
  case sa :Array[String] =>
    sa.length < 2 || sa.sliding(2).forall(x => x(0) < x(1))
  case ia :Array[Int] =>
    ia.length > 2 &&
      ia(0) == 1 && ia(1) == 1 &&
      ia.sliding(3).forall(x => x(0) + x(1) == x(2))
  case _ => a.length == 3
}
```

usage:

```
arrTest(Array("John","Margaery"))          //true  (Strings in order)
arrTest(Array("John", "Basquiat", "Yoda")) //false (Strings out of order)
arrTest(Array(1,1,2,3,5,8,13))             //true  (Fibonacci Ints)
arrTest(Array('z', 'k', 'b'))              //true  (3 Chars, any order)
arrTest(Array(3.1, 4.4))                   //false (2 Doubles)
```